# How can I pop out the contents of a sublist in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a question about python programming in python2.7.

If I have a list A and I want to pop the last element D2, how can I do that?
When I just type A.pop() it pops the entire sub-list rather than D2.

```
A=[['HQ', 'H6', 'SJ', 'H0'],['H7', 'HK','DQ', 'DK'],
  ['D4', 'SK', 'H8', 'CK'],  ['CQ', 'S3', 'HJ', 'C9'], 
  ['S6', 'S8', 'S1', 'D2']]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`A.pop(-1).pop(-1)` should do it.

Comment: Beware that this code will also remove the whole last sublist, i.e. S6, S8, and S1.

Answer (score 5):

`A[-1].pop(-1)`

this will only pop off the element you need, nothing else. enjoy ! :)

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks for your answer.